# Cairo Dock doesn't switch between windows by [Alt]+[Tab]

Tags: compiz, 12.10, cairo-dock

I'm using **Cairo Dock** (in Ubuntu 12.10) and there is one issue: it doesn't switch between opened windows by **`[Alt] + [Tab]`**.

I'm sure, it's **not the Compiz problem**, cause **`[Alt] + [Tab]`** shortcut works well in *Unity*, *Gnome 2* and *Gnome 3*, but it doesn't in *Cairo Dock*.

What can I do to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was found here: [click me, if you have the same problem :)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9730110)

All, that you need to do is:

1. Install Compiz Manager

   `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

   Or just install via `Software Center`
2. Run Compiz Manager
3. Check in **Shift Switcher**
4. Cnange **"Next Window"** option to **[Alt]+[Tab]**.

Comment: One thing to note, if you just put "switch" in the settings filter box, it will display all the switcher plugins.  You can do basically the same thing with all of them, set next window to alt tab, and make sure the plugin is enabled.

Just recommend trying all because they definitely have different appearances.  I ended up with the ring switcher since it displays all the windows in thumbnails at once.

Comment: I did all you mentioned. But I enable "application switcher" instead "Shift Switcher" and it works properly now.

Comment: Did the above, and doesn't work on my 17.10!